# What is $$mdSelectId and when/where/why is it applied to an object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have a property `$$mdSelectId` showing up on some property OF an `<md-select>` option. The option has `$$hashKey`, and this property has `$$mdSelectId`. What is SelectId for, and why is it applied to sub properties of options?

Comment: Properties with `$$` prefix are typically used for internal angular scope tracking to assist with state comparisons within digest cyles

Comment: _**AngularJS Prefixes `$` and `$$`**: To prevent accidental name collisions with your code, AngularJS prefixes names of public objects with $ and names of private objects with `$$`. Please do not use the `$` or `$$` prefix in your code._ [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api)